# Html - two vertical divs side by side 100% height scrolling background not completely displayed

Tags: html, css, height

I have a layout with two cloumns side by side, two divs with height 100%. The content is different.

Example: screen hight is lower than the longer column. When scrolling down the background of the lower cloumn is not dislayed completely - it is to short.

How can I get two equal columns in the length of the longer one while scrolling?

This is the code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: orange;
  color: #000000
}
#container1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0
}
#container2 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #00FF00;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 300px
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <br>Content 1
  <br>
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
  et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <br>Content 2
  <br>
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` display for this purpose.

Wrapped your `container`s into a `wrapper` div and changed the `absolute` display of your containers.

Check this out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: orange;
  color: #000000;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
#container1 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
#container2 {
  background: #00FF00;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container1">
    <br>Content 1
    <br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="container2">
    <br>Content 2
    <br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternate solution**: As @Frits have answered here, you can also do this easily using a `flexbox` but it is not supported in older browsers.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: orange;
  color: #000000;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
#container1 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 50%;
}
#container2 {
  background: #00FF00;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container1">
    <br>Content 1
    <br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="container2">
    <br>Content 2
    <br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't mind you grabbing my answer and adding it as an additional resolution. In fact, I think it's awesome, let's keep all the eggs in one basket :) I will even upvote your answer for that! But fair is fair, if you add from someone else's answer in the same thread, the least you can do is mention them in your edit.

Comment: Thanks! I'll +1 for that :)

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. Unfortunatley older browsers have to be supported (>= IE 8). Both solutions, display: table and display: flex, don't bring the columns to 100% height of the viewport (Check with Rund code snippet/Full page). How can I get that?

Comment: @wolfmuc add `position: absolute;
  height: 100%;` to the `wrapper` and I think you have what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this AND simplify your CSS immensely by removing the `position:absolute;` and using `display:flex;` with a wrapping element.

[See this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/98mpsksu/1/)

All I've done in this instance is remove the absolute positioning, added a wrapping element around the two divs, and added the `display:flex;` rule.

Here's the code

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: orange;
  color: #000000
}
#container1 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#container2 {
  background: #00FF00;
}
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container1">
    <br>Content 1
    <br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="container2">
    <br>Content 2
    <br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
- the wrapper needs height: 100% and position: absolute

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style>
body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: orange; color: #000000;}
#wrapper {position: relative; height: 100%; display: table; width: auto;}
#container1 {background: #FFFFFF; display: table-cell; width: 300px;}
#container2 {background: #00FF00; display: table-cell; width: 300px;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container1">
    <br>
    Content 1<br><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br><br>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <br>
    Content 2<br><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br><br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a solution - but not the one I need. I need two independet divs. I tried two wrappers each with one conatiner - it doesn' work.